# Eliminating nuisance Instance starts

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My GCP app has been abused by some users. To stop their usage I have attempted to eliminate features that can be abused, and have employed firewall rules to block certain users. But bad users continue to try to access my app via certain legacy URLs such as [myapp.appspot.com/badroute](http://myapp.appspot.com/badroute). Of course, I still want users to use the default URL [myapp.appspot.com](http://myapp.appspot.com) .

I have altered my code in the following manner, but I am still getting Instances to start from them, and I do not want Instances in such cases. What can I do differently to avoid the bad Instances starting OR is there anything I can do to force such Instances to stop quickly instead of after about 15 minutes?

```
class Dummy(webapp2.RequestHandler): 

  def get(self):
        logging.info("Dummy:  " )
        self.redirect("/")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/badroute', Dummy)],debug=True)
```

(I may be referring to Instances when I should be referring to Requests.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you determine which requests are bad apart from those who are accessing the app via myapp.appspot.com?

Comment: They are "bad" if they request the url `.../badroute`.  That is a made up route. If they request `.../` or any other url, they are not bad. Because an Instance that is started by GCP does not stop for 15 minutes, I am getting charged for these users even though I have set max_instances in app.yaml to just 1. This app is a very lightly used app so I do not expect to be paying for Instances.

Comment: Can you add any details on how you are managing authentication & authorisation and whether these bad users are authenticated or not?

Comment: I had removed captcha because the newer version requiring object recognition in  thumbnails was too complicated for users. That may have precipitated the problems. The bad users are not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not 100% sure if this would work.

1. Create a new service `dummy`.
2. Create and deploy a `dispatch.yaml` ([GAE Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) // [GAE Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml))
3. Add the links you want to block to the `dispatch.yaml` and point them to the dummy service.
4. Set up the [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart) (IAP) and enable it for the `dummy` service.
5. ???
6. Profit

The idea is that the IAP will block the requests before they hit the `dummy` service. Since the requests never actually get forwarded to the service `dummy` you will not have an instance start. The bots will get a nice 403 page from Google's own infrastructure instead.

**EDIT:** Be sure to create the dummy service with 0 instances as the idea is to not have it cost money.

---

**EDIT2:**

So let me expand a bit on this answer.

You can have multiple GAE services running within one GCP project. Each service is it's own app. You can have one service running a python Flask app and another running a Java Springboot app. You can have each be either GAE Standard or GAE Flex. See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files).

Normally all traffic gets routed to the default service. Using `dispatch.yaml` you can make request to certain endpoints go to a specific service.

If you create the `dummy` service as a GAE Standard app, and you don't actually need it to do anything, you can then route all the endpoints that *get abused* to this dummy service using the `dispatch.yaml`. Using GAE Standard you can have the service use 0 instances (and 0 costs).

Using the IAP you can then make sure only your own Google account can access this app (which you won't do). In effect this means that the abusers cannot really access the service, as the IAP blocks it before hitting the service, as you've set it up so only your Google account can access it.

Note, the `dispatch.yaml` is separate from any services, it's one of the per-project configuration files for GAE. It's not tied to a specific service.

As stated, the dummy app doesn't actually need to do anything, but you need to deploy it once though, as this basically creates the service.

Comment: In step 2, is the `dispatch.yaml` created in the directory of `myapp.appspot.com`, not in `dummy.appspot.com`? In step 1 does `dummy` exist in its own directory separate from `myapp` and have its own  main.py?  What does `dummy`s main.py  contain?  I'm having a hard time understanding this approach, and am not even clear why the Instances in `dummy` would not potentially cost money.

Comment: see my edit, I've clarified it a bit. If you have further questions about this approach, ask away...

Answer (score 2):

So whats the objective? you want users that visit /badroute to be redirected to some /goodroute ? or you want /badroute to not hit GAE and incur cost?

Putting a google cloud load balancer in front could help.

For the first case you could setup a redirect rule (although you can do this directly within App Engine too, like you did in your code example).

If you just want it to not hit app engine you could setup google cloud load balancer to have the /badroute route to some file in a GCS bucket instead of your GAE service

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

However you wouldnt be able to use your *.appsot.com base url. You'd get a static IP which you should then map a custom domain to it

Comment: I'm having trouble researching the second alternative, (which is more like what I wanted). For example, what would be the cost savings and cost increase, how to "get a static IP...", would it remove or just reduce the bad Instances timing, etc. Actually, the problem may be going away by my reducing the `max_instances` to 1 and by the bad users losing interest in my app. So I'm going to hope for the best for now and wait for other ideas.

Comment: GCLB (Google Cloud Load Balancer) routes traffic to different backends based on rules / a url map. You'd define a background neg for your app engine services and one for GCS. You'd then just setup rules for which routes hit what. You reserve a static IP here https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list

Comment: At [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#instance_states) the `Residence` feature for basic scaling says "Instances are shut down based on the idle-timeout parameter. If an instance has been idle, for example it has not received a request for more than idle-timeout, then the instance is shut down." Is that talking about forcing a `_ah/stop`? When I read about `_ah/start` it said the default time is 15 minutes, but other docs say idle_timeout defaults to 5 minutes. (Sometimes it's spelled idle-timeout and others, idle_timeout). Try idle_timeout?

Comment: idle-timeout vs idle_timeout is just how its spelled in appenging-web.xml vs app.yaml. Are you on basic scaling, because i think idle_timeout only applies to basic scaling. Maybe you read that your code had 15 minutes to respond to a _ah/start request before it times out. thats different than idle_timeout's default value being 5 min. I suppose your link is forcing a _ah/stop. _ah/stop is just a courtesy webhook you can choose to handle or not. An instance will get shut down regardless of _ah/stop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using cloudflare to mitigate bot abuse, customize firewall rules regarding route access, rate limit ips, etc. This can be combined with Google cloud load balancer, if you’d like—as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69165767/806876.

## References

Cloudflare GCP integration: https://www.cloudflare.com/integrations/google-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

There is a little information I did not provide in my question about my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: mainapp.app
```

By simply removing `.*` from the url specification, no Instance start is created. The user gets `Error: Not Found`, though. So that satisfies my needs.

Edo Akse's Answer pushed me to this answer by reading [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref), so I am accepting his answer. I am still not clear how to implement Edo's Answer, though.